# How do I modify the amount of space between the heading and the chapter's number and/or name?

Tags: spacing, chapters, sectioning

Currently, the space between the bottom of my header and the top of the chapter number is quite large and I would like to be able to reduce the space between the header and the chapter number.  How would I go about doing this?

I am using the report documentclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer over at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801107/latex-positions-of-page-numbers-position-of-chapter-headings-chapters-and-tab/2803289#2803289).

To recap, I had to use:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{ command }[ shape ]{ format }{ label }{ sep }{ before }[ after ]
\titlespacing{ command }{ left }{ beforesep }{ aftersep }[ right ]
```

`\titleformat` must be specified in order for the spacing to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `\vspace` command. For example, `\vspace{-2ex}` means "move the stuff immediately following up 2 lines worth of vertical space". (1ex is is the height of a line in the current font).